# Self signed cert exported from Java KS doesn't work

Tags: java, c++, ssl, openssl, keytool

I'm having an issue exporting a self signed client cert from java key store into a pem file. I want to have my C++ SSL server program validate this self sign cert. If I create the self signed cert through openssl it works i.e. the server validates the cert. If I use a self-signed cert exported from JKS it doesn't get validated and the handshake fails. I use the the following SSL functions on the server for client cert validation.

```
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(*ctx, szloc, NULL)
SSL_CTX_set_verify(*ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);
SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth( *ctx, 0 );
```

I printed out the contents of both client certificates.

Cert that works:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 530171964 (0x1f99c83c)
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=OR, L=Salem, O=mahaus, OU=maroom client, CN=lenovo-pc
        Validity
            Not Before: Feb 27 13:21:37 2015 GMT
            Not After : May 28 13:21:37 2015 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=OR, L=Salem, O=mahaus, OU=maroom client, CN=lenovo-pc
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:d2:65:56:a8:1e:66:7b:70:c9:a2:73:ae:77:58:
                    cb:bf:bf:0a:62:66:5a:5d:34:3b:22:32:75:82:73:
                    b6:08:01:e8:0d:ab:d0:03:d8:3b:82:9d:84:2d:d0:
                    6c:86:82:f9:00:ea:19:57:2c:89:51:7d:6a:b3:f9:
                    75:4c:a2:57:df:9c:f5:96:bd:ff:f1:8c:4d:1d:17:
                    f5:b8:95:22:f2:9c:91:92:20:38:9e:b3:99:0a:80:
                    96:51:35:12:5b:4e:88:43:f0:0b:d5:02:b9:80:00:
                    1c:9a:af:42:9a:9e:44:e3:d4:c8:04:cd:11:d2:8f:
                    7f:78:90:58:bd:15:22:e1:d3:54:fd:c9:b0:65:20:
                    c4:f2:0b:37:62:40:f6:13:ab:ef:ce:c9:8a:1a:9a:
                    07:95:ad:96:9e:e4:48:a1:fd:32:a0:2a:02:5c:74:
                    4c:fd:ef:d6:13:af:a2:bb:00:f3:5c:c8:ee:a8:26:
                    fb:63:a3:50:81:45:88:44:03:dc:99:60:81:52:6b:
                    c7:51:e2:30:fd:68:90:f1:95:74:f8:72:23:56:3d:
                    35:16:18:a1:03:e0:87:36:d0:8d:ce:99:19:b0:57:
                    c7:3d:2a:86:d0:78:91:d8:2c:df:a2:1b:42:34:3b:
                    d1:cc:6d:96:34:73:b3:1b:31:ce:1b:36:7a:43:38:
                    45:95
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                EA:E7:82:0D:CA:DD:8A:F6:89:99:04:65:5F:F4:6E:30:91:FE:80:41
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        6a:a1:2c:42:57:7b:9c:18:88:e4:98:8d:e3:a8:9b:ca:c9:5f:
        9e:5a:c0:23:95:f6:e8:b3:44:0e:70:77:11:52:b2:de:a6:e1:
        a9:0a:66:fc:3a:b2:e9:f2:53:14:fa:5e:7b:69:c9:fe:de:64:
        4d:40:b3:a3:c7:cb:c7:cd:87:79:0c:2d:f4:f1:8c:54:fa:44:
        75:17:16:05:a7:14:d8:60:fd:20:3a:ec:49:9c:27:96:53:8e:
        9d:93:24:2d:cb:f2:f9:1c:ee:da:90:75:6b:5f:9e:f4:fd:fc:
        60:97:ab:d6:7a:61:89:25:26:a0:15:ed:9e:02:ba:4e:02:50:
        83:bc:06:2b:23:6a:74:50:87:2e:17:8d:3f:1f:f0:c9:4f:08:
        36:b8:4d:62:53:e6:5a:f5:d3:c2:71:11:58:5d:4f:91:24:32:
        c9:ee:33:8a:c3:24:64:e3:80:7b:28:e1:5c:ca:84:02:ef:71:
        d0:0a:a0:09:95:82:34:f1:3a:06:19:9e:01:fe:6c:92:a4:a5:
        da:d7:05:29:90:3b:26:7a:b9:19:33:7e:be:fc:59:cb:d0:9e:
        28:80:57:ed:e4:b6:95:19:31:c7:4b:62:26:16:53:0b:fc:ef:
        d9:88:9b:1a:a6:99:d7:4b:73:ad:15:97:c2:6e:12:75:77:d1:
        60:5f:bb:41
```

Exported cert from JKS that doesn't work:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            cd:19:9c:68:d1:c5:ca:c2
        Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=IL, L=Springfield, O=macompany, OU=yourus, CN=ABC
        Validity
            Not Before: Feb 27 19:23:33 2015 GMT
            Not After : Feb 27 19:23:33 2016 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=IL, L=Springfield, O=macompany, OU=yourus, CN=ABC
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:db:ef:24:8e:ee:3e:b1:14:18:8e:ba:17:ee:68:
                    34:d2:ac:98:29:53:97:f0:a4:21:c7:82:4c:10:ab:
                    97:17:dd:b6:88:ca:63:ad:68:7b:85:ed:94:93:64:
                    b4:53:f2:d4:ce:2f:9e:a2:3b:87:70:66:20:f3:ad:
                    30:e1:a0:31:0d:80:dd:c6:38:ed:5d:ec:d7:5c:a2:
                    89:d6:c6:ad:a1:7d:63:1a:df:5b:8b:6d:c5:94:f1:
                    fc:58:0e:a1:6f:f5:24:11:ed:be:06:f3:f1:dc:a7:
                    d3:43:c6:a2:b4:68:e5:20:ba:bd:1b:7c:f8:29:69:
                    79:f5:69:07:c1:ec:a8:78:dc:65:74:ed:bd:72:b1:
                    72:36:5b:b7:2a:a7:d3:2b:f2:45:af:64:62:de:e4:
                    4d:8b:2f:68:f3:24:bd:33:38:dd:17:00:64:e6:c2:
                    c8:2e:85:36:a2:52:6d:f7:dc:59:70:84:a2:23:7e:
                    f3:29:d6:ee:1e:07:06:c5:2a:37:3d:b2:05:b4:44:
                    82:c4:7c:a6:30:a4:90:96:f6:7a:1a:58:3c:e6:11:
                    ee:17:3d:3c:6c:b5:0d:46:b1:71:78:b5:b1:99:73:
                    aa:05:aa:a3:9f:10:ed:03:63:ae:30:c8:b2:62:a5:
                    77:d2:a0:b4:1f:f7:db:ca:bf:02:a2:f6:5a:91:91:
                    e2:9f
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                D5:FA:5F:9D:75:7A:DB:6F:D5:4B:62:CF:59:6D:BC:B5:AE:63:78:8D
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:D5:FA:5F:9D:75:7A:DB:6F:D5:4B:62:CF:59:6D:BC:B5:AE:63:78:8D

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        4f:c4:26:bf:4d:04:09:30:4b:75:31:25:73:48:15:aa:34:7c:
        fa:86:b1:63:49:e2:4d:67:5c:9b:de:4a:39:f4:a3:58:fe:f5:
        13:bf:ac:b6:81:9f:37:f4:db:c9:80:e8:fe:3b:f4:2a:54:5c:
        95:1d:56:9a:1e:10:10:c9:7e:12:05:b6:f6:17:60:1a:b1:8e:
        33:49:56:87:9d:ba:7d:56:02:7b:2d:82:81:98:12:a5:b2:b1:
        33:db:ef:e5:b0:f3:96:c0:65:0d:6f:a9:5d:e9:81:fc:78:a5:
        07:f1:3f:f7:64:0c:13:58:25:ff:b1:73:b7:bf:d3:a2:ac:f3:
        d4:c9:e4:ed:1c:92:30:ef:00:d8:e8:ba:a2:69:6a:e0:07:18:
        a1:20:e5:e4:fd:1a:c9:91:0e:7b:7b:e7:81:e3:ad:8f:b2:88:
        5e:ee:dc:a9:36:e5:75:a4:0d:26:26:2c:f2:8e:99:de:0f:5e:
        0b:a6:85:c4:b8:88:ca:43:43:b7:27:23:f0:d6:94:b6:e9:8d:
        b2:ad:a1:f4:d5:62:ff:4e:ec:9a:4f:3b:73:a0:32:0c:3a:cb:
        dc:3b:7c:26:72:bf:68:39:da:44:eb:95:ef:02:86:f6:be:46:
        8d:62:82:d9:59:6d:1a:ce:a8:09:ed:16:fe:e1:12:72:9b:0c:
        a6:10:22:47
```

BTW this cert is loaded successfully on the C++ client side, meaning there is no mismatch with the private key on the client.

The one difference I see which I surmised might have something to do with this problem is the exported cert is missing the following info about the CA under `X509v3 extensions` section:

```
    X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
        keyid:D5:FA:5F:9D:75:7A:DB:6F:D5:4B:62:CF:59:6D:BC:B5:AE:63:78:8D

    X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
        CA:TRUE
```

Is this the reason the 2nd (exported from JKS) cert validation on the server is not working? If so, how would I export the necessary extensions? If not then what else could it be?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Those extensions are not required.  They are handy if you want to trace through a chain by hand, but have no impact on validation.  The main difference is who signed them, Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption vs sha1WithRSAEncryption.  Read the docs to see what container file holds your trusted CA certs for that platform and load up the CA cert for the cert that isn't working (the CA for a self signed cert is the self signed cert itself, making it a root CA).

Answer (score 1):

You don't *always* need an Authority Key Identifier (AKI) to successfully validate an x509 certificate. The details are in the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3280.txt) but I think self signed certs (including root CAs) do not require it. Also, both of the certs you listed above appear to have valid AKI values, so I don't think that is your issue. If these certs were created with openssl or Java keytool then the AKI values are perfectly fine.

My guess is that your chain of trust is broken for the cert that doesn't successfully validate. Your server (C++ program) is getting it's trust chain from somewhere - in Java the trust chain usually comes from the cacerts file located at `jre/lib/security/cacerts`. To successfully validate, your self signed certificate would have to be listed as a trusted issuer. You can add a trusted issuer in Java with the keytool command `keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias yourCert -file file.cer`. I am not sure of where your C++ trust store is located or what the equivalent command is.

Looking up your listed function calls, it looks like those are OpenSSL functions, so your OpenSSL trust store will have to contain your self-signed certificate as a Trusted Root CA. It looks like there are instructions online for various systems, just look up "OpenSSL trust store".

Comment: Oh OK. So the self signed cert I create with openssl which works must add it to the openssl key store list of trusted certs automatically at creation time, based on what you are saying. Would you agree? Therefore I probably need to add the exported cert to the openssl keystore's list of trusted certs?

Comment: @user2722568 Yes, for a server to validate a client certificate, the server's trust store must contain the client's certificate authority (CA). That's why if you go to any https website, the browser will give you a certificate error if the browser's trust store does not list the server certificate's CA. I'm not sure where the trust store is located that your C++ program relies on, you haven't given enough details. If this is a Windows Server, you can open mmc.exe, add the "certificates" snap-in, then add your cert as a trusted root CA.

Comment: Yea everything is on Windows. OK I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: @user2722568 Looks like you're using an OpenSSL API not a Windows API, so you'll probably need to put your self-signed cert into OpenSSL trust store as a trusted root CA. (In other words - my instructions for windows probably don't apply in this situation).

Comment: Yea of course, I say that exact thing up top. See my first response. Thanks.